# What is the radius of convergence of Taylor series of $ e^{- \frac{1}{z^2}} $ about $z_0 \ne 0 $

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I am pretty new to complex analysis and we have just studied Taylor Series, so sorry if my question is basic.

I have been trying to solve this homework problem but I am not sure my solution is formal enough.

In class we proved the following theorem:

> If $f:\Omega \to \mathbb {C}$  is analytic on $\Omega$ then $f$ is representable in $\Omega$ by power series. In fact, if $ D (z_0,r) \subseteq \Omega$ (where $D(z_0,r)$ is the open disc of radius $r$ around $z_0$) then $$ f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n, \:\:\:\:\: z\in D(z_0,r) $$
> This series is called the Taylor expansion of $f$ about $z_0$.

**MY ATTEMPT**:

Now, since $f(z) = e^{- \frac{1}{z^2}} $ is analytic in $\mathbb {C} \setminus \{0\}$ as a composition of analytic functions in $\mathbb {C} \setminus \{0\}$, we have from the theorem above that for a given $z_0\ne0$ our $f(z)$ is representable as a Taylor series about $z_0$. This means that the Taylor series about $z_0$  converges uniformly to $f(z)$ on each open disc $D(z_0,r)$ which does not contain $0$. This fact implies that $r$ (the convergence radius) has to be smaller than the distance between $z_0$ and $0$ which is exactly $|z_0|$. So we conclude that the radius of convergence is $|z_0|$.

**END OF PROOF**

Is this proof correct and formal enough?

To make it more formal I was thinking maybe I could find the Taylor expansion of $f$ about $z_0$ and then use the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem to find the radius explicitly. To find the Taylor series I tried using the Taylor series of $g(z)=e^z$ which converges uniformly to $g(z)$ everywhere in the complex plane, and then subtitute $z$ with $-\frac {1}{z^2}$ for each $z\ne0$. To use the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem I tried to write the series I got as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$ for some $a_n\in\mathbb {C}$, but then things got a bit ugly... Is all this really necessary, or one can just settle for the attempt above?

So to conclude, I would like to know if the proof above is good enough, and if not I would appreciate any idea on how to improve it or any other suggestions or hints regarding another formal proof.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your conclusion doesn't quite make sense. The radius of convergence should be a positive real number, and in particular a constant. It should not depend on $z$, so to say that the radius of convergence is $|z_0|$ does not make sense. Holomorphic function are locally representable by Taylor series, and in particular the radius of convergence around a point is the distance from that point to the closes singularity. Now, since this function is holomorphic in the punctured plane, the radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: @Fenris Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but $z_0$ is a given non-zero point and hence a constant number which does not depend on $z$. As you said, the radius of convergence around a point is the distance from that point (in our case $z_0$) to the closest singularity point (which is a single point in our case and is 0), and that distance as far as I understand is $|z_0-0|=|z_0|$. Am I wrong? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't catch that the question concerned the Taylor series about $z_0$, sorry! Then you are precicely correct!

Comment: @Fenris: A small nitpick, but an important one: the radius of convergence is *at most* the distance to the closest *non-removable* singularity. Otherwise we could just remove any point from the domain of a function and thereby reduce the radius of convergence of its power series expansions. Or we could increase the radius of convergence by removing a closed disc around a non-removable singularity, making it no longer a singularity.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos thank you, you are of course right in that we should specify «to the closest *non-removable* singularity». However, I think your second point is close to moot. Removing a closed disc around a non-removable singularity from the domain of the function does not change the convergence properties of the series. The series will converge in the greates disc around $z_0$ in which $f$ is analytic (up to removable singularities).